# How to stop downloading the Json result from WebAPI method?

Tags: json, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api

I have certain functionality that is returning a custom object from WebAPI method. In Chrome it is working and showing a modal dialog but where as in IE it is downloading as json data file and prompting for Open,Save and Cancel options.I have mentioned the return type as Custom type and returing the custom filled object.

Can anyone help me on this why it is working differently in IE .

Comment: can you please show the Http request & response from both IE and Chrome's Network tab?